# Why does our Moon not have rings?

Tags: the-moon, planetary-ring

While our Moon is full of craters, one could consider that these events might have been enough to release amounts of fragmented mass into the Moon's orbit sufficient to establish some sort of ring.

Why is there no lunar ring then?

Comment: Mascons probably would have caused particles' orbits to decay.

Comment: Closed ejecta orbits are intercept orbits, since Keplerian orbits loop back over themselves.

Comment: @ConnorGarcia should mention that the moon itself is thought to have formed from ejecta that formed a ring. However, it formed from a planetary mass of ejecta with significant self-gravitation and drag interactions in a massively multi-body system where Keplerian orbits aren't applicable. Lunar impacts were rather smaller scale.

Comment: well my understanding is this, that our Earth hasn't a ring so how come our moon can have! Simple and easy!

Comment: @Gamin8ing   Earth could have a ring,but just does not have one.  Earth is much smaller than the giant planets which have rings.  But Earth is much larger than minor planets like 10199 Charikio, 2060 Chiron, anddDwarf planet Haumea which have rings.  It is theoretically possible for both Earth and the Moon to have reings.  They don't have rings, because they either  never acquired rings or lost their rings though varius processes.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_system#Rings_systems_of_minor_planets_and_moons

Comment: @M.A.Golding Thanks I didn't knew that at first, thats sounds weird but awesome!